# lucene : how to manage memory allocation?

Tags: memory-management, lucene

I'm new to lucene. And I have some puzzled about lucene's manage memory.

- Lucene whether need user to make sure memory size it can use?
- Or if needn't,how to automatically manage memory allocation
  according to the machine memory size in lucene?

uh,This question is not limited to lucene,everyone can tell me some general suggestions about memory manage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two interesting, memory related, Lucene items to look at:

1. [MMapDirectory](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html) - Uses OS caches to load parts of a lucene index into memory for faster lookups.
2. [DEFAULT_RAM_BUFFER_SIZE_MB](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html#DEFAULT_RAM_BUFFER_SIZE_MB) - Sets the memory buffer size, before storing in disk, when writing to an index - bigger value usually means better write performance (if you're I/O bound).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the IndexWriter configuration API:  http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html

Setting the java heap space can, of course, help, see:  http://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/java/-Xmx-settings

And then you practices and policies on managing the index will have an impact.  Reducing very expensive operations is helpful, such as optimization, or heavy batches of insertions or deletions, etc.

If you are really looking for how to manage memory in General, I would instead direct you to this resource:  https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask (here are just a couple examples of [entire](http://www.buy.com/prod/memory-management/31027492.html?listingId=-1&s_kwcid=) [books](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/3174967917264424199?q=memory%20management%20book&hl=en&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bpcl=38897761&biw=1044&bih=854&sa=X&ei=d_q0UPuhH8q5igKSo4CYDw&ved=0CFkQ8wIwAQ))